# How do you represent text in WKT

Tags: well-known-text

I need to label the simple-features/shapes in a Well-known text file. Is there some best practice on how to achieve this? Should I just keep the labels as separate entities linked to the WKT or is it possible to add this to the WKT itself? Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As far as I know WKT doesn't really support any kind of label as it just represents the geometry itself.  What you could do is however just store it as comma separated  list eg:

```
feature1label, {WKT string}
feature2label, {WKT string}
```

You should then be able to display this with X GIS program.  QGIS can open and display text files with a comma separated list of WKT objects using the Delimited Text plugin.

Comment: Nathan is right, the OGC WKT for Simple Features only talks about how to define the feature geometries with text, not the attributes.  I would link directly to their documentation, but they require you to accept their license agreement to view the 'Open' specification.